# How to wrap parallel ItemsControls?

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have 2 ItemsControls parallel to each other. The first is a set of TextBlocks with Property names and the second is a set of `TextBoxes` with Property values.

```
Property1   Value1

Property2   Value2

Property3   Value3

   "          "
```

The list goes on very long in some cases.

Is there a way to possibly break the columns at a certain point and 'wrap' the two `ItemsControls` so they begin 2 new columns (parallel to the first 2) in the same container?

Comment: Before looking into hackish examples of achieving this (not sure if it's at all possible, even) - why do you need two separate ItemControls? What's wrong with just one, with two columns?

Comment: Well each of the ItemsControls are bound to a different ObservableCollection. Is it possible to have a compound ItemsSource in an ItemsControl for creating 2 columns?

Comment: You can definitely roll out your own observable collection that would aggregate items from two other collections as pairs (you always have 1-to-1 match in items, right?). This would probably be a different question, however.

Comment: Yes, they're always 1:1. What I'm going to do is go ahead and merge the Property and Value properties into a single object: myObject. Then I'll set up the binding to the ItemsControl (Path=myObservableCollection<myObject> then template a horizontal stack panel with both the textblock (Path=PropertyN) and textbox(Path=ValueN). I set the ItemsPanelTemplate to a vertical wrappanel and this will accomplish what I need to do. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty confident that this cannot be done. This isn't even `ItemsControl`-specific - your question really boils down to, "how do I take two separate WPF controls, and make their children display in interleaved manner?". It just doesn't work that way - after all, an `ItemsControl` is still a `UIElement`, and has well-defined `Width` and `Height`. In your example with two interleaves `ItemsControl`s, what would be the width of each?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this question is that you are dynamically creating the Property*n*, Value*n* TextBlocks.

Host the whole thing in a *WrapPanel* control.

For each pair of TextBlocks you dynamically create, create a new *Grid* control, and place the two TextBlocks in this *Grid* control and place the *Grid* control in the *WrapPanel* control.

---

**Edit** After Pavel's comment, I realise that you currently have the two lists as two single separate controls. My solution suggests a completely different approach.

Comment: What "each pair"? He only has 2 `ItemControl`s in all here.

Comment: @Paul: Oops, I misread the question. I was thinking each pair of text blocks, but you're right, they're just two separate lists.